# Characterization of Continuous Linear Transformation

Tags: functional-analysis

The Question is: Let $V$ & $W$ be two Normed Linear Spaces & let $T: V \to W$ be a linear transformation. Show that: $T$ is continuous iff $T$ maps Cauchy Sequences in $V$ into Cauchy Sequences in $W$.

The result seems to be obvious if the spaces are complete; i.e. assuming the limit of the Cauchy sequences being in the space. For general case, I am unable to prove it!!

Thank you!!

Comment: Use the fact that linear transformation is continuous if and only if it is bounded.

Comment: Thank you  Michael Greinecker! But using necessary & sufficient condition for continuity, i.e. boundedness I have proved that the images of a Cauchy Sequence under the linear Transformation will be again Cauchy!! .. Can you please help me out in proving the converse implication??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$T:V\to W$ is continuous if and only if it is bounded, that is if there is $B\geq 0$ such that $\|Tx\|_V\leq B\|x\|_W$.

If $T$ is not continuous, then we can find for each $n$ some $x\in V$ such that $\|Tx\|_W>n^2\|x\|$. But then $y=x/\|x\|_V$ is a norm-$1$-vector with $\|Ty\|_W>n^2 $. So we can find a sequence $(y_n)$ of norm-$1$-vectors such that $\|Ty_n\|_W>n^2$ for all $n$. But then $(y_n/n)$ converges to $0$ and is therefore a Cauchy sequence. Yet $\|Ty_n/n\|_W>n$ for all $n$, so $(Ty_n/n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence, since every Cauchy-sequence is bounded.

The other direction is straightforward.

Comment: Hmm... I was trying to prove it directly, didn't think about yielding a contradiction! Thank you 
Michael Greinecker!